# Динамическое добавление блоков через select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы старые инпуты удалялись?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control').change(function() {
    var x = $("#select").val();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < x) {
      $('#input').append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your name">');
      i++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

 <select class="form-control" id="select">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
  <section id="input">
  
  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Что значит старые? имеется ввиду сохраненные ранее?

Comment: Да, чтобы количество инпутов было таким же как значение селекта. Мне уже дали нужный ответ. Спасибо за отклик)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#input').empty();
while (...
```